# Hibernate query throwing

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

The following query is throwing an exception. Loan class has a variable of type User so I'm passing the user object to the query.

```
String hqlQuery = "SELECT " +
                "l.outDate, l.dueDate, l.noOfRenewals, " +
                "c.authors, c.title, c.yearPublished, " +
                "f.amount " +
                "FROM Loan l " +
                "JOIN CatalogueEntry c " +
                "INNER JOIN Fine f " +
                "WHERE l.user=" + user + 
                " AND l=f.loan" +
                " AND l.catalogueEntry=c";
```

The exception thrown is:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@' [SELECT l.outDate, l.dueDate, l.noOfRenewals, c.authors, c.title, c.yearPublished, f.amount FROM com.csu.library.mvc.dto.Loan l JOIN CatalogueEntry c INNER JOIN Fine f WHERE l.user=com.csu.library.mvc.dto.User@6f349665 AND l=f.loan AND l.catalogueEntry=c]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1735)
    at com.csu.library.mvc.dao.implementation.LoanDaoImpl.getLoansByUserForDisplay(LoanDaoImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.getLoansByUserForDisplay(Unknown Source)
    at com.csu.library.mvc.service.impl.LoanServiceImpl.getCurrentLoansForDisplay(LoanServiceImpl.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.getCurrentLoansForDisplay(Unknown Source)
    at com.csu.library.mvc.controller.UserController.homepage(UserController.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

***Both loan and catalogueEntry are object variables and not just primitive variables.***

Comment: you should write like:  `"WHERE l.user='" + user + "'"` ,, notice in where condition

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan After I added the changes, following error is thrown.
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT l.outDate, l.dueDate, l.noOfRenewals, c.authors, c.title, c.yearPublished, f.amount FROM com.csu.library.mvc.dto.Loan l JOIN CatalogueEntry c INNER JOIN Fine f WHERE l.user='com.csu.library.mvc.dto.User@3865db85' AND f.loan=l AND l.catalogueEntry=c]

Comment: sorry then No idea :(

Comment: It is not an answer, but you better use query parameters instead of concatenation. It is more secure and you won't need to worry about whether to use quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reframe HQL to something like this:-

```
"WHERE l.user.id=" + user.getId()
```

where `id` is the primary key of the `User` class.

The reason being giving `user` in the query, is appending its `toString()` representation in the actual query.

**Update:-** For the `JOIN`, you need to mention the `ON` clause too.

```
JOIN CatalogueEntry c
ON l.someField = c.someField
```

The same goes for the `JOIN` with `Fine` too. Make those changes, and see what happens!

Comment: Following error is thrown. org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT l.outDate, l.dueDate, l.noOfRenewals, c.authors, c.title, c.yearPublished, f.amount FROM com.csu.library.mvc.dto.Loan l JOIN CatalogueEntry c INNER JOIN Fine f WHERE l.user.userID=2 AND f.loan=l AND l.catalogueEntry=c]

Comment: okay.... but I have a list of fines in loan. so how am i supposed to map that in the query? l.fines.someField = f.someField?? I'm sure that is not right.

Comment: you needn't do that. It'll fetch multiple records.

Comment: can you suggest a particular way to match the records?

Comment: which record do you need to match, with what?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28982/discussion-between-nick-s-and-r-j)